# Make ModelForm Field Larger in Django

Tags: html, css, django

I have a ModelForm where there is a description field.  Django generates the field at its standard size but I'd like to make it, say, twice as large.  I seem to be failing at Googling how to do this.

HTML

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

  <div class="container">
    <form method="POST">

      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="column">
          <label for="form.reference">Reference ID: </label><br>
          <!-- <input type="text" value="{{ reference_id }}">-->
           {{ form.reference }}
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
        <div class="column">
          <label for="form.description">Description: </label>
          <br>
          {{ form.description}}
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <label for="form.cases">Cases: </label>
          <br>
          {{ form.cases }}
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <label for="form.count">Count: </label>
          <br>
          {{ form.count }}
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
          <br>
          <br>


      <button type="submit" name="add_mani" style="border-color: #7395AE;">Add Line</button>
    </form>
```

Forms.py

```
class CreateManifestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Manifests
        fields = ('reference', 'cases', 'description', 'count')
```

Again I am looking to increase the size of the field for 'description'

Comment: all you need to do is write some css for classes `.description .column` to change the sizes of the field.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is write some css. For example you can write like this:

```
# custom.css
.description .column input {
     width:500px;
}
```

Now, you can write this code as inline in the template. Or if you save it somewhere for example `/static/css/custom.css`, then you can add it to the template.

Lets say if you added your existing css in base.html like this:

```
# base.html

{% block css %}
// some css imports
{% endblock %}
```

Then in your `add_manifest.html` file you can try like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block css %}
{{ block.super }}
<link href={% static 'css/custom.css' %}>
{% endblock %}

// rest of the code
```